# Fossil ID: possible fauna fossil, from Perlis, Malaysia

Tags: geology, fossils, paleontology, carbonate, identification-request

I found this fossil while doing my fieldwork in limestone area. Description below may help to identify it.

Location: NW Perlis, Malaysia (Setul Formation). Hilly Area.

My Observation:

1. Have a curly shape
2. It have line and look like a suture
3. Does not have visible feature of cephalopod like septa and chamber.
4. It can be found between layer of stromatolite
5. Other fossil found nearby: gastropod, cephalopod and brachiopod (most of this fossil already have been damage but the shape still good and can easily identify it.

Size of the coin: 2.2 cm.

I hope this information is helping to identify the fossil. Thanks.

[image: Plan View of the fossil and its has curly shape]

[image: Look like a suture]

[image: The "suture" still can be seen from the inside]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please include location and description of the place where you found it. [Is there something else you can improve in your question](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1760/20559)

Comment: @Universal_learner already edit based on your guidelines. I hope it help but correct me if i am wrong. thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thank you. Upvoted. We have some paleontologists in the site. Let's see if you can have an answer

Comment: I have started a bounty because you provided info and this is a good question. Let's see if someone answer you!

Comment: changing the title to  indicate it is a marine fossil will help get more traffic. But you may have to take it to a museum, Cambrian fossils can be particularly difficult to identify quickly, since they are so different than things alive today. you need someone vert familiar with Cambrian fossils.

Answer (score -1):

it looks like a gastropod, as there are no septa. Maybe it is Malayaspira, which is Ordovician